# WinAPI | Unregister RawInputDevice

Tags: winapi, raw-input

How can I unregister from RegisterRawInputDevices()?

Comment: Terminate the program.  Or start ignoring WM_INPUT.

Comment: That's no option. I need to gain the possibility to switch between different devices I want to observe. Thus, the longer the application runs, the more devices will be registered to my window. Is there no other way?

Answer (score 5):

A quick look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645565.aspx) indicates that you might make some progress by calling `RegisterRawInputDevices` with the `RIDEV_REMOVE` flag in the `RAWINPUTDEVICE` structure. At least, that's where I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But RIDEV_REMOVE is not what I'm looking for. MSDN: "This tells the operating system to stop reading from a device".

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: What little information I can glean from the documentation and some chatter on the MSDN forums indicates that this really is the way to go. It's highly unlikely that `RIDEV_REMOVE` will cause the OS to stop reading from the device. That's probably a documentation error that's supposed to say that it will stop sending you messages from the device. It looks like to unregister you call with `RIDEV_REMOVE` and with an `hwnd` parameter of null.

Comment: actually, calling RegisterRawInputDevices with RawInputDeviceFlags.REMOVE and handle set does nothing. The handle registered is still receiving messages.

Comment: 1/2 When I called `RegisterRawInputDevices` with `RIDEV_REMOVE`, my application did stop receiving `WM_INPUT` events for the specified device type - keyboard, but the application also stopped getting the keyboard state using DInput8 API `LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8::GetDeviceData`. So keyboard completely stops working in the application after calling `RegisterRawInputDevices` with `RIDEV_REMOVE`. When I call `RegisterRawInputDevices`, I set my `dwFlags` to 0: I do not set it to `RIDEV_NOLEGACY`.

Comment: 2/2 It means that the documentation does what it says: it tells operating system to stop reading from a device, but only from the point of view of the current application. The keyboard still working in all other applications.